# Jupyter convert to .pdf no template sub-directory with name 'latex'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter, nbconvert

When running the command

```
python -m jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'latex' found in the following paths:
        /Users/stan/Library/Jupyter
        /Users/stan/Library/Python/3.11/share/jupyter
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/share/jupyter
        /usr/local/share/jupyter
        /usr/share/jupyter
```

I have latex installed (verified with `latex --version`) as well as `python@3.11`, `nbconvert` and `jupyter`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I cannot find this error anywhere else online.